# Any sample code for componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet? (on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, string, substring

I want to split a long string received from a server to a few substrings. The separate characters are different.

Are there any sample code for method: componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet? Or may I ask a simple code to split "A~B^C" to "A", "B" and "C"?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"A~B^C";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
          [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"^~"]];

NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Comment: Thanks indeed. Is NSLog just a log? Must I use the Log every time I deal with an array?

Comment: It's just a log to show the elements in the array, it should write A, B, C seperate

Comment: @epatel The whole world is busy with truncating the special characters in a string and adding to array,but I only want the value before special character occurrence in a string,say for instance I have string with multiple strings @"hen@a bird,lizard@reptile,....",I just want to add hen,lizard to the array :)